# How do I initialize a variable before jQuery cloning/animating

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing this snow animation and I want to reduce FPS by half on some browsers, so for that I have to only move the dom half the times. I need to set a variable after cloning/animating for each flake.

I can't set the variable before the cloning because then the "i" variable would be general, and for each flake it would be increased, it needs to be set within the flake scope.

```
            $flake.clone().appendTo('#snowContainer').css({
                left: x,
                top: y,
                opacity: startOpacity,
                width: sizeFlake + '%',

                *** I need to initialize the "i" variable here,
                or somewhere before the loop "step" starts ***

                color: options.flakeColor
            }).stop().animate({'border-spacing': 0 },{ 
            step: function(p, fx) {

                angle += 0.01;
                xadd = (Math.sin(angle) + (sizeFlake/4) * 1.5)/speed;
                yadd = (Math.cos(angle) + (sizeFlake/2) / 2)/speed;

                x += xadd;
                y += yadd;

                *** if "i" variable here is not defined it throws an error ***

                if(i%2==0)
                {
                    var move = {top: y + "px", left: x + "px"};
                    $(fx.elem).css(move);
                }
                i++;

            }, duration: 20000, easing:"linear", complete: function (){ $(this).remove(); //console.log("flake deleted");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you create an preview of your code running on something like [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? If we can tinker with the code, it will help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the start callback of animation

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

> start
>
> Type: Function( Promise animation )
>
> A function to call when the animation begins. (version added: 1.8)

or check the p parameter of the step callback function to intercept only the first step of the animation.